# Element CSS declaration in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

Below is the content I extracted from one WordPress site, no matter how I set the custom CSS, the setting doesn't be affected and same as the result as http://jsfiddle.net/yckelvin/19m6trhk/

I tried

```
.privacypolicy_privacypolicy table thead th {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #e35094;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}
```

or more specific to element

```
#post-289 .privacypolicy_privacypolicy th {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #0091D3;
    padding-bottom: 3%; 
}
```

None of them be affected. It seems there is something overriding the declaration.  How do I directly find the correct element and apply the CSS declaration? Is there any way to do debugging in Chrome?

Main Content in WordPress Page

```
<main id="main" class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <article id="post-289" class="post-289 page type-page status-publish hentry entry wpautop">
            <div class="wrap" background-color:="" rgba(255,255,255,0.4); "=" ">
                    <div class="entry-content ">
                        <div class="privacypolicy_privacypolicy ">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="3 ">Privacy Policy use of personal data in direct marketing</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3 "("The Ordinance "), the Group will respect the laws of Hong Kong in accordance with Chapter 486, "the Personal Data (Privacy) Ordinance, " Your Excellency statutory right to privacy and is committed to protecting your personal information. Given that the regulations on direct marketing aspects of the latest amendments have been made, as well as users of the personal data, we hereby provide the Group's implicit policy statement for your reference.
                                    </td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th colspan="3 ">1.Overview</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th></th>
<td>1.1</td>
<td>The main explanation of this Privacy Policy Statement, the Group's how to use your personal data in direct marketing. Described in this article, "we ", "our " means any member of the Group.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>1.2</td>
<td>Such as English and Chinese versions of this Privacy Policy Statement there is any conflict or disagreement, the English version shall prevail.</td>
</tr>
<tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="3">8.Data retention</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td colspan="2">To meet the purpose of collecting data, we will retain your personal information is necessary under the circumstances. Personal information will no longer need to be destroyed.</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
</tbody>
</table></div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </article>

            <div id="comments ">
                            </div>

    </div>


    <div id="sidebar " class="four columns ">
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: to see what styles are applied to which element in chrome, press F12 or right click on the element and select "inspect element"

Comment: Amit Joki, what invalid html? please advise. This is only part of the WordPress page but not the whole.